Autopilots: how do they work and how would I implement them
I recently am taking on autopilots, and I dont really know where to start. I want to make a realistic autopilot in my game engine, but I dont know exactly where to start. Is there any sites, documents or videos which start out easily (without all the complex formulas) and then dives deeper into those formulas and why they work?
All I know is an autopilot works with many different systems, and here I come with a bit of advantage. In my game engine, the only forces acting on my plane are the standard lift, drag weight and thrust. Turbulence and all those other obscure, scary things dont exist, so I dont have to worry about the things related to that.
Thanks anyway!

If the physics are simple enough and target realism low autopilot can be implemented by turning OFF some or all of the physics and handing control of speed/heading to the 'autopilot' code and saying it is just really good at it's job of dealing with the physics. Downside of this is odd results entering/leaving autopilot and potentially allowing impossible altitude/speed combinations.

If you don't want to use complex formulas, I suspect that you haven't implemented realistic flight dynamics.
If your flight dynamics are simple enough, you may not need an autopilot at all.  If the user stops inputting anything, the airplane should probably fly straight and level.
Without realistic flight dynamics, why would you need a realistic autopilot?
Common kinds of autopilot are altitude hold, attitude hold, and heading hold.
Altitude hold maintains the current altitude.
Attitude hold maintains the current climb/descent attitude.  You can be in either altitude hold or attitude hold -- but not both at the same time.
Heading hold maintains a compass heading over the ground (say in the presence of winds).
You can probably implement these kinds of modes without any realistic flight dynamics or controls.

Hi there! So for a bit of clarification, I'm trying to remake an airbus MCDU, where you can input a bunch of waypoints, and the computer takes them all in and slowly moves the plane towards them. I needed an autopilot so that the plane doesnt go 90 degrees and pulls back like a fighter jet, but instead turns calmly

I would simply program your 'autopilot' to perform a standard rate turn -- 3 degrees per second, i.e. a 360 in two minutes.  If you look up the equations for a steady turn, you'll find the relationship between turn rate, bank angle, velocity, g's pulled (i.e. lift required) etc.
